# Javascript - animate element to center of screen from any position

Tags: javascript, animation, physics, trigonometry, game-physics

I have a red div that the user can click and drag around anywhere on the screen.The grey div is positioned relative to the red div and updated automatically as the red div is moved. Scrolling with mouse wheel should cause the red div (and subsequently the grey div) to animate from whatever position they are to the center of the window and then stop.

So far I have the current coordinates, the target coordinates, and distance, and the angle in degrees. They are being logged to the console as such.

Plunker of what I have so far:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Oi517Hbat7WgIoOu0oFW

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
You are encouraged to share your code that you've got so far with us. And explain, what you have tried to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.body.clientWidth`  to get the width of the browser window and `document.body.clientHeight` to get the height then set the div to the centre ie:-

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById('mydivid');
mydiv.top = ((parseInt(document.body.clientHeight) / 2) - (parseInt(myDiv.Height) / 2)) +'px';
mydiv.left = ((parseInt(document.body.clientWidth) / 2) - (parseInt(myDiv.Width) / 2)) +'px';
```

If you want it to 'glide' to the centre, you can add some transform styles to the CSS

```
    div.#mydiv {
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;  
    -moz-transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;  
    -o-transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;  
    -ms-transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;  
    transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;  
}
```

Animates the move to the centre over 1 second time frame

Comment: Thanks Paul - I realize I switched changed some aspects of the question to use mousewheel instead of click event to begin animating the div towards the center. I also linked to plunkr.I really appreciate your time and help. You're solution is great - my question needed to be improved.

Answer (score 0):

are you using jquery?

use .animate() you can tell it to move based on CSS properties (from http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
$( "#mydiv" ).animate({
  width: "70%",
  opacity: 0.4,
  marginLeft: "0.6in",
  fontSize: "3em",
  borderWidth: "10px"
}, 1500 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I can't use jquery it's more along the lines of game logic I assume some trig and maybe physics are involved?